# Is is possible to use the userId in meteor Accounts.onCreateUser?

Tags: meteor

I want to initialize the default variables for a user on creation. Is there a good way to do this - I've tried using the userId in the onCreateUser without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, the _id is now valid in OnCreateUser as of Meteor 0.5.8...

Answer (score 1):

You could simply extend the user collection to add any properties you want:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  // We still want the default hook's 'profile' behavior.
  if (options.profile) {
    user.profile = options.profile;
    user.profile.user_status = "new";
  }
  return user;
});
```

This will not update any collection other than `users`, so it cannot be used to the store the new user `_id` as a foreign key in another collection.

Comment: Thanks @DavideWihl. I was hoping to be able to initialise other collections though using the reference to the user. I could always check for it later but it seemed cleaner to do it on user creation if possible.